# What is the "cross product" of $n-1$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ called?

Tags: notation, terminology, cross-product

Is there a name for the following determinant ($v_1, ... v_{n-1}$ are vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$)?

$$\det\begin{pmatrix}
\mathbf{e_1}&\cdots&\mathbf{e_n}\\
(v_1)_1&\cdots&(v_1)_n\\
\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
(v_{n-1})_1&\cdots&(v_{n-1})_n\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: It can be formulated in a coordinate-free way using exterior powers and Hodge star. So, a perfectly valid notation (and definition!) would be $\star(v_1\wedge v_2 \wedge \dots \wedge v_{n-1})$.

Comment: Wikipedia calls it the [generalised cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Multilinear_algebra), albeit with the row of vectors moved to the bottom for reasons they explain.

Comment: [Wedge Product](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WedgeProduct.html)? But this might be too generalized I guess